# Custom Pixel tracking code to track user activity or stats

Tags: php, cookies, statistics, tracking, pixel

I'm in process of developing a  pixel tracking code , that will sit on external websites (checkout confirmation page).  Pixel tracking is currently  done using a image tag which calls a `PHP` file.

**Background scenario:**

1. `User A` visits a page on my site, click on a link ( A product).
2. User  taken to external site - product page
3. User then click `buy now` and proceeds to checkout.
4. Once checkout process is completed  `pixel tracking` called at the end.

**I need  to know  how i can track the following stats or data for each unique/individual user :**

1. Track the page the users left or exit
2. Track what page user landed on
3. Track if user made the purchase for that item or not

Comment: Piwik probably already does all this - can you use that rather than developing from scratch? It is essentially Google Analytics that you can host yourself.

Comment: @halfer i prefer using my own method since i understand the process more, Im not to sure how i would integrate Piwik.

Comment: It's extremely easy. You host it like any other web app, set up some simple configuration, and then you put their tracking pixel on your website using the full domain address. It is much, _much_ easier than writing your own, by a long shot.

Comment: @halfer Can Piwik create pixel code, which i can give out to online stores?

Answer (score 1):

You must have access to the external website, and be able to change their code. Otherwise, it is not, and obviously should not be, possible.

So, you put your pixel on all their pages. With that pixel you can send information to the server you do the tracking on. For instance the page the pixel is on. Suppose your pixel is:

> http://www.mypixeltracking.com/mypixel.php

You can add data to that by using arguments:

> http://www.mypixeltracking.com/mypixel.php?id=2723252&page=/home.html

Your `mypixel.php` PHP script can pick this up and put it in a database. That's the basic idea. You can add the arguments on the external server with JavaScript or in their codes.

You might still wonder how you make a pixel in PHP? See here: [Developing a tracking pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079666/developing-a-tracking-pixel/13079838#13079838)

The types of tracking you want to do can be done by looking at the information in your database.

Comment: how do i identify or track  each user?   should I set a cookie with user's IP address?

Comment: IP addresses won't do, they change or are shared. A cookie is a good idea, as long as it contains a unique session id. It's not perfect however, for instance when a single customer uses more than one computer or erases the cookie. There are clever ways to identify them as the same, for instance after a login, but do you want to go that far? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id