# How to check URLs of sites which are displaying images from my server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

is there a possibility of tracking URLs that display images directly from my web server?

for eg. somebody copy URL link of image from my website and display it on his. Can i somehow get his site URL?

Comment: You should see this subject, it can help you a lot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079666/developing-a-tracking-pixel

Answer (score 1):

You can check the apache logs - see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored) for finding them. `access.log` would be appropriate in this case. The referer column is probably the one you're looking for, see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog) for more about apache logs.

If you only want to allow the images to be displayed on your website, open up a root `.htacess` file, and enter the following:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.com
```